# How to change the replication of a vgroup in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

I'am using TDengine as a time-series storage engine. How could I change the replication of a vgroup from 2 to 3? During the change, should I do or not to do something?

Answer (score 0):

try following commands in taos shell

```
alter database db replica 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it will sql statement:

```sql
alter database dbname replica 3.
```

Here's the full list you can use with alter for a database:

- keep: days to keep data in the database
- cache/blocks: the memory cache for vnode: cache*blocks
- wal
- fsync
- replica
- cachelast
- quorum

See more details in docs for [Database Management](https://www.taosdata.com/docs/cn/v2.0/taos-sql#management)